# Removing applied displacement modifiers

Tags: modifiers

I clicked "apply" on 2 displacement modifiers to a plane and it really messed up the look I was going for. I went to go edit the modifiers but I can't see them. In my hierarchy my plane looks like it has no modifiers at all even though I've done a lot to it.

How do I find/edit the modifiers I applied to the plane?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you clicked "Apply" the only way <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> to undo, but if you already close the file or made other changes, you can't go back and you need to start over.

Comment: It would be good to expand this answer to mention *why* this is the case - ie, because “Apply” specifically removes the modifier by making the change to the mesh permanent.